# How to use the "OR" operator when writing a scripted field in Kibana 4.2?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I tried: `doc['ABCD'].value=="CZ" OR doc['ABCD'].value=="GEO"? "Allowed": "Blocked"` and i'm still getting an error.

`ABCD` is the field name. I'm not sure whether the format of the script is wrong or if there is a problem with ES itself. For more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633524/what-is-the-correct-format-for-a-ternary-operation-in-kibana][1]

Comment: Have you tried `||`?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. Well there is a conflict i guess because the result of this operation is a string. Lucene can access only numeric values. If that's the case how can we perform operations which results in string?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you created another field in your document based on that logic before sending the document to ES?

Comment: Yes, but again creating too many fields would make indexing longer. I just read this https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3180 and seems like there is no solution for string type fields. So I guess the only way is to create a separate field.

Comment: One field won't kill you, believe me. Or at least kill you less than dynamic scripting or if you have to bang your head against the wall to bend Kibana to make it work :)

Comment: Well you're right ;) But was just seeing if there could be another solution. Moreover, creating a field for the above categorization to happen during indexing for sooo many log lines will take a longer time :)